# Dropdown misses one listItem at runtime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I have a dropdown `ddlMerchant` which `loads` at runtime.

```
Sub LoadMerchant()

        Try
            Utilities.GetTerminal(ddlMerchant, -999, -999, "-999", "-999", "-999")
            ddlMerchant.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", -999))
            ddlMerchant.SelectedIndex = 0

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

And the code for `Utilities.GetTerminal`

```
 objBox.Items.Clear()
            Try
                Dim drTemp As SqlDataReader = GenericDB.ExecuteSPForDataReader("spGetTerminal", CountryID, CityID, MerchantID, TerminalID, POSSerial)
                While drTemp.Read()
                    Dim sTerminal As String = ""
                    sTerminal = drTemp.Item("TerminalID") + " : " + Convert.ToString(drTemp.Item("MerchantName1"))
                    objBox.Items.Add(New ListItem(sTerminal, drTemp.Item("TerminalID")))
                End While
                objBox.SelectedIndex = 0
                drTemp.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
```

Problem is, It loads and insert all items of the `result set` but it just misses 
the second Item. Although I can see that second Item  in `sTerminal` during debugging but It doesn't show in the `dropdown`.
Here is the dropdown binded which doesnt show second Item
[image]

And here is the result set I get in SQL Server when I execute the stored procedure, where you can see the dropdown is missing an Item with Terminal ID `00000002`, although It is returned
[image]

Comment: Terminal 000000009 is missing too right? could it be simply a flag in the stored procedure?

Comment: There is no Terminal 000000009. To see all terminals refer to second picture. This is the result set I get when I execute the stored procedure on SQL server. But in case of dropdwon,it is missing one item

Comment: yes you're right... i was looking at the merchantID

Answer (score 0):

First entry (select) in your dropdown looks to be missing too.

`ddlMerchant.Items.Insert` looks to be the problem. Try moving this into the `Utilities.GetTerminal` function and just after clearing the items (`objBox.Items.Clear()`), add the 'Select' option and then followed by the entries from your Database